# Accidentally ran a chmod command on the "/" root directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, chmod

I accidentally ran a

```
sudo find -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

on the root directory of my server as I was logged in from a sudo user

I rebooted the server which seems to still be running fine, I also compared the permission of some folders and files to another server I have and couldn't notice any difference in file permissions.

I am not sure how to revert this or the magnitude of the damage that this may have caused.

If someone can give me a specific/crucial file with its permission so I can check if it matches, as I am not sure if the command took effect.

Can someone help me out please? Thanks

Comment: Check `/etc/shadow`. It should be `0640`. The files `vmlinuz*` and `System*` under the `/boot` directory should be `0600`. Check also with the `journalctl` command for strange messages in the system log.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems I dodged a bullet, pfeww, permissions still the same

Comment: The only way I can imagine that your server is still booting at all is if it managed to make `/bin/chmod` non-executable before doing too much damage

Comment: @Terrance I am running sudo commands normally

Comment: Look also at `/bin` and `/usr/bin` with command `ls -al`. Are all files executable (i.e. they have three `x`s). Also, how long did the command `sudo find -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` ran? Did you kill it? Did it finished with an error message?

Comment: @Terrance bin/chmod is still 755.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli it ran for a while i tried killing it but it wouldn't stop, it ended in a long list of errors that operation permission was denied for everything inside the proc directory , and yes all files in usr/bin are executable

Comment: @Terrance the `-exec` command will inherit the `find` command's EUID I think? try `sudo find / -type f -exec whoami \; -quit` for example

Comment: @steeldriver Well, then this is the luckiest person on the planet and I am out of here.  I can't explain why none of the permissions seemed to be changed.  Never mind, I am thinking xargs anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that this was run from the root directory?

Comment: @pLumo 100% sure, I m considering the fact that because I wasn't logged in as root user, I got a permission error on everything inside the 'proc' directory, the server for some reason reverted the changes..I don't know if its possible but nothing seems to have changed